# How to use a logger library in a Windows Service developed in Visual C++

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2010, logging

I managed to create a Windows Service through MS Visual C++ Express 2010 but debugging the application seems an uphill task. I tried to use existing C++ logger libraries ( tried both Apache Log4CXX and Log4CPP) but it is not working. 
When I use the logger in general application program, it works fine but with my service it doesn't.
Can anyone please guide what am I missing? Including additional headers, linking additional libraries all things are in place in the project. Is it the logger library being static? 
Please help as I am stuck at this trivial issue being new to Visual C++ and Win Services.

Thanks,
Wasim

Comment: What do you mean by it is not working? Do you mean you cannot find the output log files, or the output log file contains nothing, or the logging cause the service to stop, or ...

Comment: I cannot find the output log files., Its not getting generated. Service is running fine.